# jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap not working

Tags: jquery, eclipse, cordova, jquery-mobile

I;ve just started working with PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile in Eclipse. I'm trying to make a basic android app but for some reason I cant seem to get the jquery mobile to work. Here is the error in the log cat:

```
01-28 13:35:58.870: E/Web Console(535): TypeError: Result of expression 'a.browser' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.mobile.js:2
```

[image: Screen Shot of Eclipse]

I've made a js folder and placed the jQuery and jQuery Mobile js in the folder, I assume in the html my path is correct. I've the same with the css and for some reason I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: This isn't exactly your bug, but your code refers to cordova-1.5.0.js when in reality you are using 2.3.0. Try fixing that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a closer look you will see you are using cordova 2.3 js file in your eclipse project but at the same time you are referencing cordova 1.5 file in your HTML.

**EDIT :**

Next thing to look, have you used last versions of jQuery and jQuery Mobile. You can download them from my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/QXJrk/. Also check that you are using jQuery version 1.82 (don't use 2.0 yet).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css">    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! I've made the change and still the same problem

Comment: Take a look at my Edit segment.

Comment: BINGO!!! I was using one of the latest versions of jQuery and thats what was causing nothing to work!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! Changed to the 1.8.2 version and its working great!